# ACF loadmore flexible content - how to make it work right?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I need to show 4 flexible items and load more, I don't know how to make it manually, so I tried [that plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more-for-acf/#description)  But I can't understand how to make the shortcode correctly
That's what I generated

```
[ajax_load_more container_type="div" acf="true" acf_field_type="flexible" acf_field_name="review-repeater" post_type="any" meta_key="review-repeater" meta_value="" meta_compare="IN"]
```

The original flexible content loop without loadmore

```
      <div class="row justify-content-center">   
           <?php if( have_rows('review-repeater') ):
             // Loop through rows.
             while ( have_rows('review-repeater') ) : the_row();?>         
             <div class="rev">
               <?php                  // Case: Paragraph layout.
                 if( get_row_layout() == 'review-repeater' ):?> 
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="rev-left">
                      <div class="raiting-review"><?php echo get_sub_field('review-raiting'); ?></div>
                      <div class="review-content">
                      <p><?php echo get_sub_field('review-content'); ?></p>
                      <div class="d-flex">
                         <?php echo get_sub_field('review-author'); ?> , <?php echo get_sub_field('review-date'); ?>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rev-right"> 
                        <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('review-platform') ?>">  
                        <p><?php echo get_sub_field('review-count'); ?></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>  
                
             </div>
            <?php  endif;
             // End loop.
             endwhile;
         endif; ?>
```

I copied that code to the 'repeater template' instead of default post archive loop, but the shortcode doesn't show my content, maybe someone already used the same decision?

Already tried posts_per_page="4" parameter, it didn't help too.